# How to concatenate two arrays value into an other one

Tags: php, arrays

I use Fullcalandar and i need  concatenate  two  array  into `$eventsArray['title']`

I need to do something like that for title ( this method don't work...)

```
$eventsArray['title'] = $items['subject'] + $items['eventname'];
```

My code

> foreach ($eventgroup as $items){
>
> ```
>   $eventsArray['title'] =  $items['eventname'];
>   $eventsArray['start'] =  $items['date'];
>   $eventsArray['weekends'] =  'false';
>   $events[] = $eventsArray;
> }
> ```

How can I do this please ?  Thx

Comment: it should be a dot sign not a + sign. $eventsArray['title'] = $items['subject'] . $items['eventname'];

Comment: In php the string concatenation operator is the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
....
$eventsArray['title'] =  $items['subject']. ' ' .$items['eventname'];
...
```

Read this [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs)

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate use the dot

```
 $eventsArray['title'] = $items['subject'].$items['eventname'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more readable method:

```
$eventsArray['title'] = "$items[subject] $items[eventname]";
```

Comment: Except that for accessing array items you need `"{$items['subject']} {$items['eventname']}"`

Comment: @Juhana Wrong! Wrong! Wrong! http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple